# (JS) Why is my While Loop not working!? Perhaps I don't understand the basic concept

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Here's the code:

```
var n = 4;
while(n) {
console.log("Hey!");
n = 5;
}
```

Am I right here:

n is a variable, with value 4.

while n = 4, print "Hey" in console.

change value of n to 5.

check if n = 4.

n is not equal to 4, so stop executing the code!

Where am I wrong? I'm really frustrated! Edited it a million times! And the worst thing, browser crashes every time!
Please correct me!

Comment: Both `4` and `5` are truthy values, so the loop just keeps on going until `n` is a falsy value, which never happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I right here:
>
> n is a variable, with value 4.
>
> while n = 4, print "Hey" in console.

`while(n)` *doesn't* check to see if `n` is `4`, it checks to see if `n` is *truthy**. Both `4` and `5` are *truthy* values.

To check if it's `4`, use `==` or `===`:

```
while (n === 4) {
    console.log("Hey!");
    n = 5;
}
```

(For more about `==` vs. `===`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) and its answers.)

---

* JavaScript uses type coercion in many places, including when testing conditions for `while` loops and similar. So we talk about values being "truthy" (they coerce to `true`) or "falsey" (they coerce to `false`). Truthy values are all values that aren't falsey. The falsey values are `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`.